# PHP Count number of specific words said via Twitter

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

Using Twitter's oAUTH... I want to know if it's possible to rummage through a person's tweets and count how many times a person has a certain word in their tweets...

What say you, possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Other questions?

Comment: Nope. That's all. I'll figure out the how-to myself. It's more exciting that way! :D I just didn't want to spend hours upon hours and then getting a "no, you actually can't do that." :P

Comment: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline you can get the last 3200 tweets and process it as you wish.

Comment: dang. Who tweets that much? Thanks.

Comment: honestly.. just read through it... no clue what to do :| damn.

Comment: oauth twitter (abraham's twitteroauth library is great) and then `file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=12345');` and then process. More than that, ask a new question IMO. Or edit this. Also you might want to accept my answer :)

Comment: @Jahkr: if you have any questions about [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) feel free to hit me up on Twitter as @[abraham](https://twitter.com/abraham)